# Is there an official Facebook Graph Search API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Most of you must have heard seen the new Facebook Graph search. I have browsed trough a dozens of documentation pages, but could not find a complete API for this.

I know a very similar result could be achieved using the current Graph API, but it would not worth the hassle to build it from scratch.

My question is: Is there an official Facebook Graph Search API?

Comment: Not yet. But we can hope they're working on it.

Comment: May be using FQL could be easy, you can query public objects

Comment: Did you find anything by now?

Comment: Nope and still nothing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Graph Search hasn't even rolled out to the entire public.

> We're very early in the development of Graph Search. It’s only available in English today and you can search for only a subset of content on Facebook. Posts and Open Graph actions (for example, song listens) are not yet available. We’ll be working on these things over the coming months.

<sub>http://newsroom.fb.com/News/562/Introducing-Graph-Search-Beta</sub>

And developers are now only optimizing their apps to be discoverable by Graph Search

> Apps are now more discoverable on Facebook with Graph Search. In addition to showing up in search results based on your app’s name, they can show up in search results based on criteria like "strategy games my friends play" or "apps my friends who live in San Francisco use." To optimize your app for Graph Search, please make sure your app details are up-to-date and that your app is properly categorized.

<sub>https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/01/16/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/</sub>

The latest API development is collections and sections

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/05/14/create-beautiful-sections-for-your-app-on-timeline/

There is no official Graph Search API yet, if it was, it would have been announced via one of the following places

- Developer's Blog - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/
- Roadmap - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

And appear here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's detailed and complete

Comment: Is the Graph Search API still unavailable? How to search for old posts, http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-search-for-old-facebook-posts/

Comment: Also, this page seems to be down, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/

Comment: @1.21gigawatts yes it is still not available.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts link fixed

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a tool called Graph explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

You might find FQL query useful, like this one to search for friends of a user living near a particular location:

```
SELECT name, uid, current_location.latitude, current_location.longitude FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND current_location.latitude > 41 AND current_location.latitude < 42
```